# how to split text by "\n\n" Android?

Tags: android

In my string.xml I have a text which contains 2 paragraphs "\n\n". When I try to split it by `String.split("\n\n")`
or `String.split("\\n\\n")` it does not work. Knows anywhone the reason?

and here it is the sample data:

[image]

it displays well on the screen

[image]

Comment: The first version should be working.  Can you add sample data?

Comment: Please make sure you defined all string locale same format, agree with @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, added sample data

Comment: If \n\n is located together not in separated strings, does it work?

Comment: Sorry, previous was wrong, use that `String.split("[\n].[\n]")`

Comment: @grabarz121 `String.split("[\n].[\n]")` - This is wrong too.

Comment: @AndreyMolochko it's strange, because in my case this is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val content = resources.getString(R.string.test).split("\n \n ")
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="test">first
        \n
        \n
        second</string>
```

You should add gaps after `\n`. Use my pattern for spliting and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Your text appears to actually have *literal* `\n` values in it.  In that case, you may try  splitting on `\\n` (which becomes `\\\\n` in Java syntax):

```
String yourText = "Part one \\n Part two";
String[] parts = yourText.split("\\\\n");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[Part one ,  Part two]
```